# deserialize a JSON and modify a single attribute in the list of Object

Tags: apex, json, deserialize, httpresponse, parser

I have a JSON string as below from a http response.

```
{
    "agreements": [
        {
            "agreementId": "ag0",
            "publishedDate": "04-03-2016 00:00:00",
            "AgreementNumber": "00001",
            "description": "test agreement"
        },
        {
            "agreementId": "ag1",
            "publishedDate": "04-04-2016 00:00:00",
            "AgreementNumber": "00002",
            "description": "test agreement"
        },
        {
            "agreementId": "ag3",
            "publishedDate": "04-05-2016 00:00:00",
            "AgreementNumber": "00003",
            "description": "test agreement"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using JSON.desrialize and getting it in a custom wrapper class. Everything is working fine.

My requirement is to get only the date for the  `publishedDate`. My current approach is after deserialization, i use a for loop where i modify the result with `publishedDate.substring(0,10)` to get only the date.

is there any other better way to get only the date in `publishedDate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format you are getting is not a standard datetime format according to [salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) and [w3.org documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

[image]

If you get the [properly formatted datetime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm) then using below will give you correct date:

```
String currDT = '2016-04-10 00:00:00';
Date myDate = Date.valueOf(currDT);
```

However, if you are not able to get properly formatted date and getting only what is mentioned in question then you need custom logic. Better approach compared to `publishedDate.substring(0,10)` is to use `publishedDate.split(' ')[0]`. However for getting proper [Date Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm), you can do as below :

```
String dtStr = '04-05-2016 00:00:00';
List<String> attrs = dtStr.split(' ')[0].split('-');
Integer myYear = Integer.valueOf(attrs[2]);
Integer myMonth = Integer.valueOf(attrs[1]);
Integer myDay = Integer.valueOf(attrs[0]);
Date myDate = Date.newInstance(myYear, myMonth, myDay);
```